# Type safe generic array in c

Tags: c, array

Here is my type safe dynamic array.  I'm eventually going to make a hash table in C.  I'm just wondering if anything seems wrong or out of place.  Thanks.

````c
#ifndef DARRAY_HEADER_INCLUDED
#define DARRAY_HEADER_INCLUDED

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

#define darray_deff(name, type)\
struct name {\
    size_t capacity;\
    size_t size;\
    type *data;\
};\
void name##_grow(struct name *const _array, size_t const _capacity);\
void name##_reserve(struct name *const _array, size_t const _capacity);\
void name##_destroy(struct name *const _array);\
void name##_push(struct name *const _array, type const _value);\
void name##_push_unintialized(struct name *const _array, size_t const _amount);\
void name##_pop(struct name *const _array);\
type *name##_begin(struct name *const _array);\
type *name##_end(struct name *const _array);\
void name##_clear(struct name *const _array);\
int name##_empty(struct name *const _array);\
void name##_zero(struct name *const _array);\
\
void name##_grow(struct name *const _array, size_t const _capacity) {\
    type *data = realloc(_array->data, _capacity * sizeof(type));\
    assert(data);\
    _array->data = data;\
    _array->capacity = _capacity;\
}\
void name##_reserve(struct name *const _array, size_t const _capacity) {\
    if(_capacity > _array->capacity) {\
        name##_grow(_array, _capacity);\
    }\
}\
void name##_destroy(struct name *const _array) {\
    free(_array->data);\
    _array->capacity = 0;\
    _array->size = 0;\
}\
void name##_push(struct name *const _array, type const _value) {\
    if(_array->size == _array->capacity) {\
        size_t const capacity = (_array->capacity ? _array->capacity : 1);\
        name##_grow(_array, capacity * 2);\
    }\
    _array->data[_array->size] = _value;\
    ++_array->size;\
}\
void name##_push_unintialized(struct name *const _array, size_t const _amount) {\
    if(_array->size + _amount > _array->capacity) {\
        size_t const new_capacity = _array->size + _amount;\
        name##_grow(_array, new_capacity);\
    }\
    _array->size = _array->size + _amount;\
}\
inline void name##_pop(struct name *const _array) {\
    --_array->size;\
}\
inline type *name##_begin(struct name *const _array) {\
    return _array->data;\
}\
inline type *name##_end(struct name *const _array) {\
    return _array->data + _array->size;\
}\
inline void name##_clear(struct name *const _array) {\
    _array->size = 0;\
}\
inline int name##_empty(struct name *const _array) {\
    return _array->size == 0;\
}\
void name##_zero(struct name *const _array) {\
    memset(_array->data, 0, sizeof(type) * _array->size);\
}\

#endif //  DARRAY_HEADER_INCLUDED
```
````

Comment: Could you please provide your test case file as well. Macros without any demonstration of usage are difficult to review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reduce clutter**

`const` of an *object* serves little purpose in *declarations* other than to clutter code.  This is the interface users often reference to understand the code.  Make it easier for them.

```
// void name##_grow(struct name *const _array, size_t const _capacity);
void name##_grow(struct name * _array, size_t _capacity);
```

**Add `const` to enquiry functions**

```
// int name##_empty(struct name *const _array);
int name##_empty(const struct name *const _array);
//               ^^^^^
```

**Use `bool` for logical results**

```
#include <stdbool.h>

// int name##_empty(struct name *const _array);
bool name##_empty(struct name *const _array);
```

Aside: personally I like `isempty()` vs. `empty()`.

**Tolerate a `NULL` on *destroy***

As `free(NULL)` is OK, allow `name##_destroy(NULL)` to simplify clean-up.

**Guard against popping an empty table in `name##_pop()`**

**Missing `name##_shrink()`**

It differs from `name##_grow()` in that shrinking to 0 and a result of `NULL` is OK.

I'd expect a good hash table function set to shrink selectively as well as grow.

**Useful to add `name##_apply()`**

`int apply(array, state, func)` applies function `func(state, &element)` to each element of the array.

Apply to each element as long as return value is 0.  With a non-zero return, stop applying to the rest and return that value.

Very useful for printing each element and iterating the array.

**`pop()` misnamed**

I'd except a *pop* to return a value.

```
// void name##_pop(struct name *const _array)
type name##_pop(struct name *const _array)
```

**Deeper**

There are advantages for having a hash table size that is a prime - better hashing.  To that end, for `.capacity`, I'd use an index into a look-up table of select primes - typical primes just smaller than powers-of-2.

Comment: For shrink would i use a combination of free( if given capacity is 0 ) and realloc( if given capacity is less than current capacity )?

Comment: Im actually confused by "Tolerate Null on destroy".

Comment: @LeadVaxeral Looks [good](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/277309/type-safe-generic-array-in-c/277321?noredirect=1#comment549243_277321).

Comment: @LeadVaxeral `name##_destroy(NULL)` and is bad it attempts `_array->data`, `_array->capacity`, ...  Code could test `_array == NULL` first.